# Determining the Boyle temperature (non-numerical)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, gas

I have been given the following equation of state (in relation to [ideal gas laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law)):

$$PV_{m} = RT \left( \ 1+\frac{8}{57}\left(\frac{P}{P_{c}}\right)\left(\frac{T}{T_{c}}\right)\left[1-4\left(\frac{T_{c}}{T}\right)^{2}\right] \ \right)$$

and was asked to find the Boyle temperature in terms of $R$, $P_{c}$, and $T_{c}$,

where $T_{c}$ is the critical temperature, $P_{c}$ is the critical pressure, $V_{m}$ is the molecular volume, and $R$ is the gas constant.

What I tried to do was the following:

Since at Boyle temperature, real gas = ideal gas,

$$PV_{m} = RT \ ,$$

and thus by substitution and opening the brackets, I ended up with:

$$4\left(\frac{T_{c}}{T}\right)^{2} = 1$$

which is equal to $T_{B} = 2T_{c}$.

However, I am assuming that something is wrong, since I was asked to find everything in terms of $R$, $P_{c}$, and $T_{c}$ and not only $T_{c}$.

Comment: Can you define terms $V_m, \ T_c, \ T_B$ etc. ?

Comment: @BrendanDarrer while these were not defined in the question, I have defined them in terms of the usual thermodynamics syntax.